# Copy file name to clipboard and paste it in chrome omnibox

Tags: google-chrome, batch, clipboard, evernote

What I'm after is to be able to come home and have the webpages I need already open. Using a combination of IOS Siri & Reminders, Evernote, IF (formerly IFttt) and Dropbox ive managed to be able to ask siri to make a new reminder in the reminders app, then have IF link it to Evernote, and then have IF again, link Evernote to Dropbox.

I have Dropbox installed on my home desktop so the file appears in the Dropbox folder there. When the file appears its something like "John_Smith.txt" I'd like to set up a batch file that is able to copy that file name to the clipboard, and then open chrome, and then paste the file name into the chrome omni-box. Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially if someone knows an easier way to get a note to Dropbox

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, how about something like this?

```
for /R "D:\Test\files" %%f in (*.txt) do (
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" %%~f
)
pause
```

This will find all `.txt` files in a folder, then open them each in Chrome:

[image]